# want to move files in jar during merging

Tags: ant, build

I have several external jar files in /lib directory
like

> /lib
>
> /lib/A.jar
>
> /lib/B.jar
>
> /lib/C.jar

and each JAR file has same named file in their jar file. the path is META-INF/license.txt

so if I use zipgroupfileset task with dir attibute like dir="/lib/" include *.jar in jar task
META-INF/license.txt file is duplicated
XML code is below

```
<jar jarfile="${dest}/merged_jar.jar">
<zipgroupfileset dir="${basedir}/lib" />
<include name="**/*.jar"/>
</zipgroupfileset>
</jar>
```

after this works, merged_jar.jar is created but in this file, /META-INF/license.txt is duplicated

I don't want to exclude license.txt file but want to move each file's license.txt file to another folder to gather and add suffix or prefix(eg. /license/license_A.txt) during merging task

thanks to your help.

Comment: Wait until you can use a computer, and make your question much better, because I can't understand anything about it.

Comment: thanks a lot, I downloaded stackexchange apps. and add some XML codes

Answer (score 0):

Use the `prefix`  attribute to put some prefix path on the destination directory.

```
 <zipfileset dir="license" includes="*.txt" prefix="license/licence"/>
```

This will copy all text files inside `license` directory to the `license/licence` directory